# Slick の Code-generation で View を除外したい

Tags: scala

VIEWの変更権限を持っていないデータベースからコード生成を行おうとしています。
ドキュメントにはAPIをoverrideするように書いてありましたがやり方がわかりませんでした。

使用ライブラリのバージョン
scala 2.11.6
slick 3.0.3
slick-codegen 3.0.3
mysql-connector-java 5.1.36

ドキュメント
http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.3/code-generation.html#customization

ドキュメントで紹介されているExample
https://github.com/slick/slick-codegen-customization-example

ソースコードはこちらになります。

```
def custom = {
  val slickDriver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver"
  val jdbcDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
  val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
  val outputFolder = "src/main/scala"
  val pkg = "gen"
  val user = "userName"
  val pass = "password"

  val driver: JdbcProfile =
    Class.forName(slickDriver + "$").getField("MODULE$").get(null).asInstanceOf[JdbcProfile]
  val dbFactory = driver.api.Database
  val db = dbFactory.forURL(url, driver = jdbcDriver,
    user = Some(user).getOrElse(null), password = Some(pass).getOrElse(null), keepAliveConnection = true)

  try {
    val m = Await.result(db.run(driver.createModel(None, false)(ExecutionContext.global).withPinnedSession), Duration.Inf)
    new SourceCodeGenerator(m).writeToFile(slickDriver, outputFolder, pkg)
  } finally db.close
}
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

ソースを読んで解決しました。

MTable.getTables の引数に対象とするテーブルをフィルターする条件を指定します。

typesにはDatabaseMetaData.TableTypeのnameに定義されている値を利用できます。

```
def custom = {
  val slickDriver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver"
  val jdbcDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
  val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
  val outputFolder = "src/main/scala"
  val pkg = "gen"
  val user = "userName"
  val pass = "password"

  val driver: JdbcProfile =
    Class.forName(slickDriver + "$").getField("MODULE$").get(null).asInstanceOf[JdbcProfile]
  val dbFactory = driver.api.Database
  val db = dbFactory.forURL(url, driver = jdbcDriver,
    user = Some(user).getOrElse(null), password = Some(pass).getOrElse(null), keepAliveConnection = true)

  val tables = Some(MTable.getTables(Some(""), Some(""), None, Some(Seq("TABLE")))) //ここでフィルターできるようです。
  val modelAction = driver.createModel(tables, false)(ExecutionContext.global).withPinnedSession
  val modelFuture = db.run(modelAction)
  try {
    val m = Await.result(modelFuture, Duration.Inf)
    new SourceCodeGenerator(m).writeToFile(slickDriver, outputFolder, pkg)
  } finally db.close
}
```